# How to Ignore cases,space and blank lines when comparing text between two files

Tags: awk, tr

So I have written a script in which I compare between two files

so my files are 
file1:

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
```

file 2:

```
this is line 1,aaa
this is line 2,bbb
this is line 3,ccc
```

so what my code does is find if the sentence preceding(in file2) the comma exists in file and if it exists then replace it with the sentence that succeeds the comma.

Here is my code

```
awk -F'"(,")?' '
NR==FNR { r[$2] = $3; next }
{ for (n in r) gsub(n, r[n]) } 1' file2.csv file1.csv>output.csv
```

so my output.csv should look like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
```

This code works fine as long as there is no mismatch between the cases in both files and in the spaces.
so When comparing I want it to compare in a case insensitive manner and by trimming the spaces.
For eg:

```
When comparing:
file1:
thisisline1.
thisisline2.
thisisline3. etc
```

and the output should be in the original format

```
This is line 1.
```

What I am looking for is on the fly trimming and lowercase conversion

edit: Making this question clearer regarding the trim part.
I have written the code:

```
cat file2.csv|tr -s ' '>file3.csv
```

what this does is trim multiple spaces into one 
so

```
This is line 1.
```

is the same as

```
This   is line 1.
```

But the problem occurs if there exists a blank line with one or more spaces
eg:

```
this is line 1,aaa
this is line 2,bbb
(blank line but with space)
this is line 3,ccc
this is line 4.
this is line 5.
```

so when I use my awk command first and then the trim function this fails.
so even with this file my output should be

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
```

Comment: Could you please mention more clear expected output in your post.

Comment: Your sample input isn't adequate to test if a solution works or not. You should have included RE metachars and backreference chars and lines that are subsets of other lines, and lines that partially match, and lines that contain commas, and lines that differ just in white space to name but a few test cases that would help separate working from non-working "solutions".

Answer (score 1):

check this please with tolower

```
awk -F'"(,")?' '
NR==FNR { r[$2] = $3; next }
{ for (n in r) gsub(tolower(n), tolower(r[n])) } 1' file2.csv file1.csv>output.csv
```

you can also use

```
IGNORECASE=1
```

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html)

Comment: IGNORECASE=1 seems to work in my case.Thanks I'll try both the solutions on larger files and let you know.

Comment: thank you. If you feel that our answers are helpfull for you please consider to upvote and/or accept it as solution. Regards

Comment: That will fail if/when the input contains RE metacharacters and/or backreference characters and it will fail due to partial matches. It's one of those many cases where inadequate sample input/output in  the question is making it look like it works when it actually doesn't in general. Don't do it.

Comment: IGNORECASE=1 when added to my code works with the larger files too. The problem with the tolower() solution is that it permanently changes the contents of file2 which is undesirable.Thanks

Comment: thank you. If you feel that our answers are helpfull for you please consider to upvote and/or accept it as solution. Regards

Comment: Yes I have upvoted it. Any ideas regarding the second part of my problem?(ignoring whitespaces in both files)

Comment: Ignorecase makes the matching case insensitive which is half of my problem statement.However it doesn't trim spaces. So while matching if there is a blank line with a space character(this can occur if the while making the file someone presses enter then space and then enter) in file2 my entire program goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Perl, you can use the below

```
> cat anuj_f2 
this is line 1,aaa
this is line 2,bbb
this is line 3,ccc
> cat anuj_f1
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
> perl -F"," -lane ' $kv{lc $F[0]."."}=$F[1] if $ARGV eq "anuj_f2"; if( $ARGV eq "anuj_f1" ) {s/$_/$kv{lc $_}?$kv{lc $_}:$_/ige;print } ' anuj_f2 anuj_f1
aaa
bbb
ccc
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort mate.However I am not looking at PERL currently and sticking with awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key = tolower($0)
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",key)
}
NR==FNR {
    val = $0
    sub(/,[^,]+$/,"",key)
    sub(/.*,/,"",val)
    key2val[key"."] = val
    next
}
{ print (key in key2val ? key2val[key] : $0) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
aaa
bbb
ccc
This is line 4.
This is line 5.
```

Comment: I was looking to modify my code to do the task.This clearly does the job for the sample files provided.However if I were to add commas in my file1 like This is line 1,something it fails to work.My code works with this too but i just want to ignore the case and the whitespaces while comparing.Thanks for this solution though

Comment: a) your code is completely the wrong approach and will fail given various input strings as I've mentioned previously so don't try to enhance it, just start over. b) my code will work just fine with commas in file1 - if you have a counter example them please edit your question to include it in your sample input/output.

Comment: The thing is there is a standard format in which I am going to create my file1 and file2.So my code works for that format.The reason I am trying to ignore whitespaces and case is to account for any human error that may occur while creating those files(inconsistent spacing or wrong Case).

Comment: That's fine but your code will still fail given some input strings and it's trivial to simply not use that approach and use the robust approach instead. Use it if you like though, it's your application.